# get.basis() in lpSolveAPI

Tags: r, linear-programming

I am confused with the return of function get.basis(). For example,

```
lprec <- make.lp(0, 4)
set.objfn(lprec, c(1, 3, 6.24, 0.1))
add.constraint(lprec, c(0, 78.26, 0, 2.9), ">=", 92.3)
add.constraint(lprec, c(0.24, 0, 11.31, 0), "<=", 14.8)
add.constraint(lprec, c(12.68, 0, 0.08, 0.9), ">=", 4)
set.bounds(lprec, lower = c(28.6, 18), columns = c(1, 4))
set.bounds(lprec, upper = 48.98, columns = 4)
RowNames <- c("THISROW", "THATROW", "LASTROW")
ColNames <- c("COLONE", "COLTWO", "COLTHREE", "COLFOUR")
dimnames(lprec) <- list(RowNames, ColNames)
solve(lprec)
```

Then the basic variables are

```
> get.basis(lprec)
[1] -7 -2 -3
```

However, the solution is

```
> get.variables(lprec)
[1] 28.60000  0.00000  0.00000 31.82759
```

From the solution, it seems variable 1 and variable 4 are basis. **Hence how does vector (-7, -2, -3) come from?**

I am guessing it is from 3 constraints and 4 decision variables.

Answer (score 0):

After I reviewed the simplex method for bounded variables, finally I understood how it happens. These two links are helpful. [Example](https://homepages.rpi.edu/~mitchj/handouts/upperbounds/);  [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wdcD6S6C25k)

Come back to this problem, the structure is like
[image]

lpSolveAPI (R interface for lp_solve) would rewrite the constraint structure as the following format after adding appropriate slack variables. The first three columns are for slack variables. Hence, the return of `get.basis()`, which is -7,-2,-3, are column 7, 2, 3 that represent variable 4, slack variable 2 and 3.

[image]

With respect to this kind of LP with bounded variables, a variable could be nonbasic at either lower bound or upper bound. The return of `get.basis(lp, nonbasic=TRUE)` is -1,-4,-5,-6. Minus means these variables are at their lower bound. It means slack variable 1 = 0, variable 4 = 28.6, variable 5 = 0, variable 6 = 0.

Thus, the optimal solution is 28.6(nonbasic), 0(nonbasic), 0(nonbasic), 31.82(basic)